# Laravel database search optimization

Tags: laravel, optimization

Hope you are doing good!

I have a code that fetches posts from friends' posts and also from mutual friends' posts. The rule is:-

- 70% Results must be from direct friends posts
- 10% From mutual friends/ friends of friends posts

```
    function feedUpdate() {
        $friends = Auth::user()->profile->following;
    
        //Fetch friends posts
        $posts = Post::whereIn('profile_id', $friends->pluck('following_id'));
    
        //Fetch mutual friends posts
        $mutual_friends = Following::where('follower_id', $friends->pluck('following_id'))->withCount('followingFollowers')->orderByDesc("following_followers_count")->limit(10);
        $mutual_friend_post = Post::whereIn('profile_id', $mutual_friends->pluck('following_id'))->inRandomOrder()->limit(3);
        $posts = $posts->union($mutual_friend_post);
    
        return new FeedResourceCollection($posts);
    
    }
```

I believe this multiple where statements are a bit intensive.

Are there any chances of making this faster? Or any suggestions on best practices I should follow when performing this kind of multi-table query??

Comment: Why do you believe so ? Did you do any benchmark ? with Laravel seeding, you can try to make a stress test with 100K records for example and try. `where in` on indexed columns should be ok.

Comment: I thought performing multiple queries could put a load on the server and slow the performance of the application, and wanted to run hear it from someone with experience in query optimization

Comment: If you provide the generated SQL statements, we might be able to optimize it from that perspective.

Comment: @RickJames  select `posts`.`id`, `posts`.`profile_id`, `profile_rattings`.`stars`, `posts`.`created_at`, `posts`.`caption`,
`is_image` from `posts` left join `followings` on `posts`.`profile_id` = `followings`.`following_id` left join
`profile_rattings` on `posts`.`profile_id` = `profile_rattings`.`profile_id` where 1 = 1 or `posts`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?,
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `followings`.`follower_id` = ? or `profile_rattings`.`rating_profile_id` = ? order by `created_at`
desc, `stars` desc

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: `->inRandomOrder()->limit(3)` -- Does this mean you are picking only 3 "mutual friends at random"?  Or is it "3 random posts from some mutual friend"?  (Sorry, I can help you with SQL, but I don't speak Laravel.)

Comment: One `SELECT` can have only one `WHERE` clause.  What's going on?